# Unordered list spacing issue with commonsguy / cwac-richedit Library

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am using commonsguy / cwac-richedit Library for Rich Text Editing , i am parsing an html file using the below code. Library provides the bullet and i customize that to give space between bullet and text,But i am unable to provide the space before Bullet.Can you please help.

```
 try {
  SpanTagRoster tagRoster = new SpanTagRoster();
  Spanned fromInput = new SpannableStringGenerator(tagRoster).fromXhtml("<ul><li>Simple Html with some text in unordered list"</li></ul>),
    appContext, tv);

  textView.setText(fromInput);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}


      •  This is my output.
         •   I need to show line with space before Bullet.
```

Comment: You are welcome to try [overriding a stock `SpanTagHandler`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit#customizing-the-conversion) for this.

Comment: I already used BulletSpan() to create Bullet for unordered list and created some handlers also to show image and ordered list and some styles. But i am unable to give space before Bullets or index of ordered list.

Comment: I am not certain what that has to do with this library, though.

Comment: You are not certain about space or you are questioning about showing image using ImageSpan and ordered list .

Comment: Your issue seems to be with spans. You might want to start with getting what you want via SpannableStringBuilder directly, with tailored spans. Then, and only then, worry about how to create a SpanTagHandler to offer roundtrip XHTML support.